# Failed to go back to home screen from Android apps

Tags: android

I have a button in my app named "Go Home" to redirect the user to the home screen. It is working fine without the very first launch. The process of first launch is noted below:

After uploading the APK into SVN I am downloading using the web browser. Then go back to the download folder and installing the app. When install finishes I click on Open. Then In my app I click on the "Go Home" button. The application redirect me to the web browser instead of the home screen. I am tired to search a solution for that.

I am using the following code:

```
finish(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance, Siddiqui Noor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and also try putting `finish()` after `startActivity`

Comment: It works for me. But when I relaunch the app I see my "Go Back" button is selected and disabled. I am unable to click on it.

Comment: Finally I changed finish() to MainActivity.this.finish().

Answer (score 1):

Your app is opening in the task of the browser. Try this:

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's not really redirecting you anywhere, it's just closing the Activity.  You call `finish()` after which the intent to start the activity never happens.  The app is closed because you've finished the Activity and you end up looking at the screen that was showing before you opened the app.  In this case, that is the browser.

Try removing the line to `finish();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

kill your current activity after redirect the next activity

```
finish();
```